# Regular expression never matches

Tags: java, regex

I have the following entries in my log files:

```
09-22-11 12:35:09 1ms   INFO         ...erChangeSetListener:91           11  processing changeSet for class:4328,at version:1316720109100
09-22-11 12:35:09 779ms INFO         ...erChangeSetListener:91           11  processing changeSet for class:4334,at version:1316720109882
09-22-11 12:35:09 1ms   INFO         ...erChangeSetListener:91           11  processing changeSet for class:4328,at version:1316720109882
09-22-11 12:35:11 1s    WARNING      QueryServiceImpl:100                -   no existing index for class:4328
09-22-11 12:35:11       SEVERE       QueryRequest:107                    7   Aod query resulted in error:No index available for class:4328
09-22-11 12:35:11       SEVERE       AuthenticationTask:48               -   EndUserException: an error occurred when processing the query                                  Dump: /data1/amir/dev/devots/logs/dumps/22i123511.dump
```

that I'm applying this regexp to :

```
 final String pattern = "^(\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2})"  //date
                        + "[.]*" //ignore for now
                        + "(SEVERE|WARNING|INFO|CONFIG|FINE|FINER|FINEST)" //severity
                        + "[.]*"; //ignore the rest for now

 final Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(pattern);
 final Matcher m = regex.matcher(currentLine);
 if (m.matches()) {
     for (int i = 1; i <= m.groupCount(); i++) {
         System.out.format("[%d] \"%s\"%n", i, m.group(i));
     }
 }
```

But my matches never returns true.  I don't understand why.  I'd like to resiliently handle these different types of entries.  Notice the last log entry has a dump file associated with it.

Comment: Apart from the concrete question, your logs seem to be in a fixed column format. Why don't you just substring by index?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
                    + "[.]*" //ignore for now
```

The dot in `"[.]*"` only matches a literal dot, it does not have its usual meaning of "any non-line-separator character."  You need `".*"`

Answer (score 2):

You can't do `[.]*`. `.*` will suffice. You want any character, not a dot.

Test your regex here: http://regexpal.com/

Start with a very simple match and start adding complexity bit by bit.

Also, for clarity, consider naming your groups like:

```
^(?<date>\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*(?<type>SEVERE|WARNING|INFO|CONFIG|FINE|FINER|FINEST).*
```

Comment: Thanks for recommending regexpal.com, very handy to visualise the stuff in real time